# Tensorflow Auto-Encoder Sparse Data

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I'm currently in the process of adjusting my code to be able to work with sparse data and I'm stuck at this Auto-Encoder:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.Input(shape=(input_dim, 1), sparse=True),
    keras.layers.LSTM(outer_hidden_dim, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.00)),
    keras.layers.LSTM(inner_hidden_dim, activation='relu', return_sequences=False),
    keras.layers.RepeatVector(training_data.shape[1]),
    keras.layers.LSTM(inner_hidden_dim, activation='relu', return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.LSTM(outer_hidden_dim, activation='relu', return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(input_dim))
  ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')

model.fit(
  training_data,
  training_data,
  batch_size=batch_size, 
  shuffle=True,
  epochs=epochs,
  callbacks=[statistics, tensorboard_callback]
)
```

As training data I use a SparseTensor created from a COO-Matrix:

```
training_data = tf.sparse.reorder(tf.SparseTensor(
  indices=np.array([training_data.row, training_data.col]).T,
  values=training_data.data,
  dense_shape=training_data.shape
))
training_data = tf.sparse.reshape(training_data, [-1, 1, input_dim])
```

When I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
Failed to convert object of type <class 
'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: 
SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("input_1/indices:0", shape=(None, 3), dtype=int64), 
values=Tensor("input_1/values:0", shape=(None,), dtype=float64), 
dense_shape=Tensor("input_1/shape:0", shape=(3,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements 
to a supported type.
```

I tried using a custom training loop; however, I get the same error there as well. I could densify each batch in the training loop, but this would defeat the purpose of why I want to work with sparse data in the first place. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any luck on this?